# What is the reason for matplotlib for printing labels multiple times?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to write python code which will take my data and create a graph outputted to png file for each entry on the x-axis. Therefore, I can later animate the progress throughout time. However, my code for some reason, while outputting the file, it reads each plot multiple times.

I've figured it must of been my loops so I tried multiple times ensuring that I'm looping through only unique entries for the names. I went through the code step by step, but seeing that I'm new to this library, I'm not exactly sure how matplotlib is interpreting what I'm feeding it.

```py
import pandas as pa
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [['2018-10-29', 53, 'Anna Smith'],['2018-10-30', 118, 'Anna Smith'],['2018-10-31', 142, 'Anna Smith'],['2018-10-31', 7, 'Dominic Smith'],['2018-10-30', 1, 'Unknown Name'],['2018-10-29', 33, 'Jade Smith'],['2018-10-30', 103, 'Jade Smith'],['2018-10-31', 105, 'Jade Smith'],['2018-10-29', 41, 'Joanna Smith'],['2018-10-30', 169, 'Joanna Smith'],['2018-10-31', 220, 'Joanna Smith'],['2018-10-29', 31, 'John Smith'],['2018-10-30', 61, 'John Smith'],['2018-10-31', 79, 'John Smith'],['2018-10-29', 44, 'Nataly Smith'],['2018-10-30', 100, 'Nataly Smith'],['2018-10-31', 120, 'Nataly Smith'],['2018-10-30', 25, 'Sebastian Smith'],['2018-10-31', 47, 'Sebastian Smith'],['2018-10-29', 52, 'Veronica Smith'],['2018-10-30', 74, 'Veronica Smith'],['2018-10-31', 77, 'Veronica Smith']]
resultRunningTotal = pa.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'runningTotal','name']) 
resultRunningTotal['date'] = pa.to_datetime(resultRunningTotal['date']).dt.date
print((resultRunningTotal)) #print_no_1

plt.figure(figsize=(24,13.5))
TuniqueDates = resultRunningTotal['date'][~resultRunningTotal.duplicated(['date'])]
dfUniqueDates = pa.DataFrame(TuniqueDates)
dfUniqueDates.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
startDate = min(dfUniqueDates['date'])

def savePlot (tDF):
   listOfUniqueNames = tDF['name'].unique() 
   print(tDF) #print_no_2
   for n in listOfUniqueNames:
      tDF2 = tDF[tDF.name == n]
      tDF2.plot(kind='line',x='date',y='runningTotal',ax=plt.gca(),linewidth=3,label = n)

for d in dfUniqueDates['date']:
    mask = (resultRunningTotal['date'] >= startDate) & (resultRunningTotal['date'] <= d)
    tempDF5 = resultRunningTotal.loc[mask]
    savePlot(tempDF5)
    plt.savefig(str(d)+'plot.png')
```

I'm expecting for it to create:

- 1 file per each date (d) in dfUniqueDates['date']
- each of that file consists of a simple line graph where:

  - each name is represented in the same colour across all graphs
  - each name is only mentioned once in the key

See below what I do see:

- Code Output (these are fake names):
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s8Ge.png
- File Output (you won't see any names on the legend as I've removed it due to privacy):
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaIo2.png

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're plotting them all on the same figure so the labels are repeating because you are putting 3 different plots with identical labels on the same figure (so you'd see each label three times). You can see this by calling `plt.show()` at the end which gives you just a single figure that looks like this (I scrunched it down to fit my computer screen).

[image]

Because you are saving after every iteration, the graph pictures you save are different as you cumulatively add to it. However, the end result is one graph, not three. It looks like you set up your data to be cumulative so you can stop the repeating labels by using `plt.figure()` before you call `tDF2.plot()`. Like this:

```
import pandas as pa
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



data = [['2018-10-29', 53, 'Anna Smith'],['2018-10-30', 118, 'Anna Smith'],['2018-10-31', 142, 'Anna Smith'],['2018-10-31', 7, 'Dominic Smith'],['2018-10-30', 1, 'Unknown Name'],['2018-10-29', 33, 'Jade Smith'],['2018-10-30', 103, 'Jade Smith'],['2018-10-31', 105, 'Jade Smith'],['2018-10-29', 41, 'Joanna Smith'],['2018-10-30', 169, 'Joanna Smith'],['2018-10-31', 220, 'Joanna Smith'],['2018-10-29', 31, 'John Smith'],['2018-10-30', 61, 'John Smith'],['2018-10-31', 79, 'John Smith'],['2018-10-29', 44, 'Nataly Smith'],['2018-10-30', 100, 'Nataly Smith'],['2018-10-31', 120, 'Nataly Smith'],['2018-10-30', 25, 'Sebastian Smith'],['2018-10-31', 47, 'Sebastian Smith'],['2018-10-29', 52, 'Veronica Smith'],['2018-10-30', 74, 'Veronica Smith'],['2018-10-31', 77, 'Veronica Smith']]
resultRunningTotal = pa.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'runningTotal','name']) 
resultRunningTotal['date'] = pa.to_datetime(resultRunningTotal['date']).dt.date
print(type(resultRunningTotal))
print(resultRunningTotal.dtypes)

plt.figure(figsize=(24,13.5))
TuniqueDates = resultRunningTotal['date'][~resultRunningTotal.duplicated(['date'])]
dfUniqueDates = pa.DataFrame(TuniqueDates)
dfUniqueDates.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
startDate = min(dfUniqueDates['date'])

def savePlot (tDF, fig):
   listOfUniqueNames = tDF['name'].unique() 
   #print(tDF) #print_no_2
   for n in listOfUniqueNames:
      tDF2 = tDF[tDF.name == n]
      plt.figure(fig)
      tDF2.plot(kind='line',x='date',y='runningTotal',ax=plt.gca(),linewidth=3,label = n)

for d in dfUniqueDates['date']:
    mask = (resultRunningTotal['date'] >= startDate) & (resultRunningTotal['date'] <= d)
    tempDF5 = resultRunningTotal.loc[mask]
    fig_num = dfUniqueDates['date'].tolist().index(d)
    savePlot(tempDF5, fig_num)
    plt.savefig(str(d)+'plot.png')
plt.show()
```

When you call `plt.show()` at the end this gives you three different graphs that look like:

[image: figure 0]

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Comment: Thanks! that explained it :D